# How to use django base extension along with angularjs ng-include?

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I'm using ng-include like this

**HTML**

```
<div  ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl" ng-include="/static/html/main.html"></div>
```

**main.html**

```
{% extends "app\base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div ng-controller="myctrl1">
some content
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<div ng-controller="myapp2">some content </div>
```

but this is not working, it is showing an errorr "SyntaxError: Unexpected token % at Object.parse (native)"
Please suggest me a better way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what you're trying to do here. Angular templates and Django ones are quite different, even if they superficially share the same `{{ var }}` syntax. You can't inherit an Angular template from a Django one, or vice versa.

But there's no reason to want to do that anyway. Angular is already loading the template as a partial, which means it will be inserted into the div in base.html. There's no need for inheritance here at all.